# How can I combine the two panels in a duplex on one meter?

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel, nec

I own both halves of a duplex (200 amps each) which I've converted into one house. I would like to have one energy bill. Is there a simple way I can easily feed service to the second panel from the first panel from one incoming meter/service?

Comment: The _easiest_ thing may be to contact the power company to see if they can/will combine the 2 bills onto one statement for you. Can you combine the panels to one feed? Most likely. The _easiest_ way to do this is to hire someone. I'm sure the electricians will be here shortly to ask for details like square footage. It may also depend on the service capacity.

Comment: Tell us a little more about how the metering and main disconnects are set up -- do you have a meter-main (meter and main breaker only in one housing), a CSED (meter and several breakers in one housing) etc. How near are they to each other? A photo could help. Also, what have you done with the "special" areas such as kitchen and laundry -- eliminated these from one side?

Comment: What city, state, county and what power company? That may be key to getting realistic answers.

Comment: Why are they 200A services? Why does each half of the duplex *need* 200A of power?  Or did they just install a ton of extra power?  How does your heat work? Is water heater gas or electric? Dryer? Range?  Is there A/C and how big?

Comment: Who is your power company?  Can you post photos or a diagram of the existing service entrance setup?

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you have 2x 200A service, feeding that from a single meter would require a "class 320" meter (320A continuous, which is 400A derated 80%, so it matches, even if it does not appear that way at first.)

The odds are (since those are a significant step up in expense for the meter can) that you don't have that for the meters you have now. So you'd be looking at replacing the meter, with any upgrades required for the currently adopted code in your area, which include adding an outside disconnect if it's NEC2020. This could be rather expensive, will require permits and (probably) professionals and the inconvenience of having no power midway through the procedure.

As such, it will probably take a LONG time to pay off if the thing you are trying to get rid of is the monthly service fee on the second meter. Combining the bills should be easy, but may not reduce that any - could not hurt to ask, though.